# Does this "model" file belong on my Mac?

Tags: macos, file, library

My Mac HD folder has a file in it called "model". It's a txt file and quite small. I don't recall seeing it here before.

**Does anyone know what it is or what file folder it belongs in?**

[image]

I'm running Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 on a late 2012 MacBook Air with a Parallels 10 virtual machine installed.  Maybe these screen shots will help. My Time Machine is at my office, so I cannot check it until later this week.

[image]

[image]

The Sharing & Permissions show:

- **system** - read and write
- **wheel** - read only
- **everyone** - read only

Comment: Please add the content of the file (properly redacted if it contains some auth/serial info) and the build/mod date. I have never seen a file with this name there. I'd expect it to be some *bash/cli* accident.

Comment: Searching in time machine will possibly show you when it arrived. It’s not part of the core OS.

Comment: @FredHayek bmike is correct, this is not only not a part of macOS, but is not created by any 3rd party software I have encountered. Knowing the file's contents, creation date, and modification date would all be very helpful in determining where it came from.

Comment: Check the read/write permissions, that may give you some idea of what created the file. I'd also recommend using `lsof` to check and see if the file is being actively used by some program.

Comment: What does the **w/a** in *a late 2012 MBA w/a Parallels 10VM* mean?

Comment: @FredHayek "MacBookAir5,2" is the system name for the late 2012 model of MacBook air. Between that, the name being "model", and the fact that the file is read-only for everyone besides root, its likely that the file was created by a program that needed to use software that is specific to each model of Mac, and so needed a record of what model yours is. However its odd it would be saved in a file in `/` longterm, seeing as the model can be pulled from the command line at any time. I agree with JMY1000 that you should `lsof` the file, to see if it's actively being used or not.

Comment: w/a = with a, In this case, I use an MBA running a VM. Alison EE-  thank you. Can you recommend a primer on lsof's. Thank you.